# ansible gets stuck on poetry config

Tags: python, ansible, python-poetry

In my ansible script i need to perform the following tasks:

```yaml
    - name: configure access to poetry repositories
      ansible.builtin.shell:
        cmd: "{{ pyenv_root }}/versions/{{ python_version }}/envs/{{ test_facilities_env_name }}/bin/poetry config repositories.vf-test-facilities {{ vf_test_facilities_gitlab_link }}"
      environment:
        PYENV_ROOT: "{{ pyenv_root }}"
        PATH: "{{ path }}:{{ path_pyenv }}:{{ path_cargo }}"

    - name: configure access to poetry repositories
      ansible.builtin.shell: 
        cmd: "{{ pyenv_root }}/versions/{{ python_version }}/envs/{{ test_facilities_env_name }}/bin/poetry config repositories.vf-py {{ vf_py_gitlab_link }}"
      environment:
        PYENV_ROOT: "{{ pyenv_root }}"
        PATH: "{{ path }}:{{ path_pyenv }}:{{ path_cargo }}"

    - name: configure access to poetry repositories
      ansible.builtin.shell: 
        cmd: "{{ pyenv_root }}/versions/{{ python_version }}/envs/{{ test_facilities_env_name }}/bin/poetry config http-basic.vf-test-facilities {{ vf_test_facilities_gitlab_access_user }} {{ vf_test_facilities_token }}"
      environment:
        PYENV_ROOT: "{{ pyenv_root }}"
        PATH: "{{ path }}:{{ path_pyenv }}:{{ path_cargo }}"

    - name: configure access to poetry repositories
      ansible.builtin.shell:
        cmd: "{{ pyenv_root }}/versions/{{ python_version }}/envs/{{ test_facilities_env_name }}/bin/poetry config http-basic.vf-py {{ vf_py_gitlab_access_user }} {{ vf_py_token }}"
      environment:
        PYENV_ROOT: "{{ pyenv_root }}"
        PATH: "{{ path }}:{{ path_pyenv }}:{{ path_cargo }}"
```

Please ignore that this could also be done by a multiple line statement, I just splitted it for debugging purposes.

The first two tasks are running fine, but somehow Ansible get stuck on the third task.

**What I have done so far:**

**1)** To make sure it is related to the command I pass I switched the second and third statement. Then the script get stuck on the second statement. So it is definetly related to the command

```
    "{{ pyenv_root }}/versions/{{ python_version }}/envs/{{ test_facilities_env_name }}/bin/poetry config http-basic.vf-test-facilities {{ vf_test_facilities_gitlab_access_user }} {{ vf_test_facilities_token }}"
```

**2)** I also ran the script in verbose mode. The output I get on the hanging statement is

```
TASK [configure access to poetry repositories] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
    task path: /home/ansible/git/pi_setup/playbooks/voltfang_packages_installation.yml:53
    <IP_ADDRESS> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: pi
    <IP_ADDRESS> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="pi"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o 'ControlPath="/home/ansible/.ansible/cp/c2162c695a"' IP_ADDRESS '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~pi && sleep 0'"'"''
    <IP_ADDRESS> (0, b'/home/pi\n', b'')
    <IP_ADDRESS> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: pi
    <IP_ADDRESS> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="pi"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o 'ControlPath="/home/ansible/.ansible/cp/c2162c695a"' IP_ADDRESS '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/pi/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo /home/pi/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1670923014.7820504-10195-255321159434435 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1670923014.7820504-10195-255321159434435="` echo /home/pi/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1670923014.7820504-10195-255321159434435 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
    <IP_ADDRESS> (0, b'ansible-tmp-1670923014.7820504-10195-255321159434435=/home/pi/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1670923014.7820504-10195-255321159434435\n', b'')
    Using module file /home/ansible/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible/modules/command.py
    <IP_ADDRESS> PUT /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-9673_vgb1ys1/tmpdtidj7ss TO /home/pi/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1670923014.7820504-10195-255321159434435/AnsiballZ_command.py
    <IP_ADDRESS> SSH: EXEC sftp -b - -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="pi"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o 'ControlPath="/home/ansible/.ansible/cp/c2162c695a"' '[IP_ADDRESS]'
    <IP_ADDRESS> (0, b'sftp> put /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-9673_vgb1ys1/tmpdtidj7ss /home/pi/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1670923014.7820504-10195-255321159434435/AnsiballZ_command.py\n', b'')
    <IP_ADDRESS> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: pi
    <IP_ADDRESS> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="pi"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o 'ControlPath="/home/ansible/.ansible/cp/c2162c695a"' IP_ADDRESS '/bin/sh -c '"'"'chmod u+x /home/pi/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1670923014.7820504-10195-255321159434435/ /home/pi/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1670923014.7820504-10195-255321159434435/AnsiballZ_command.py && sleep 0'"'"''
    <IP_ADDRESS> (0, b'', b'')
    <IP_ADDRESS> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: pi
    <IP_ADDRESS> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="pi"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o 'ControlPath="/home/ansible/.ansible/cp/c2162c695a"' -tt IP_ADDRESS '/bin/sh -c '"'"'PYENV_ROOT=/home/pi/.pyenv PATH=/home/pi/.local/bin:/user/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/pi/.pyenv/bin:/home/pi/.cargo/bin /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1670923014.7820504-10195-255321159434435/AnsiballZ_command.py && sleep 0'"'"''
```

**3)** When I run the last command manually on the ansible host the command get's also stuck. After a keyboard interrupt the error is only at the same line in the python script. So it seems that ansible get's stuck there.

```bash
ansible@server:~/git/pi_setup $ ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="pi"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o 'ControlPath="/home/ansible/.ansible/cp/c2162c695a"' -tt IP_ADDRESS '/bin/sh -c '"'"'PYENV_ROOT=/home/pi/.pyenv PATH=/home/pi/.local/bin:/user/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/pi/.pyenv/bin:/home/pi/.cargo/bin /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1670923014.7820504-10195-255321159434435/AnsiballZ_command.py && sleep 0'"'"''
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1670923014.7820504-10195-255321159434435/AnsiballZ_command.py", line 107, in <module>
    _ansiballz_main()
  File "/home/pi/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1670923014.7820504-10195-255321159434435/AnsiballZ_command.py", line 99, in _ansiballz_main
    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)
  File "/home/pi/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1670923014.7820504-10195-255321159434435/AnsiballZ_command.py", line 47, in invoke_module
    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible.modules.command', init_globals=dict(_module_fqn='ansible.modules.command', _modlib_path=modlib_path),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 210, in run_module
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/tmp/ansible_ansible.legacy.command_payload__xj3l9tz/ansible_ansible.legacy.command_payload.zip/ansible/modules/command.py", line 401, in <module>
  File "/tmp/ansible_ansible.legacy.command_payload__xj3l9tz/ansible_ansible.legacy.command_payload.zip/ansible/modules/command.py", line 370, in main
  File "/tmp/ansible_ansible.legacy.command_payload__xj3l9tz/ansible_ansible.legacy.command_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py", line 2053, in run_command
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/selectors.py", line 469, in select
    fd_event_list = self._selector.poll(timeout, max_ev)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

**4)** I tried to run the last command  manually on the remote host and it works fine without hanging:

```
    PYENV_ROOT=/home/pi/.pyenv PATH=/home/pi/.local/bin:/user/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/pi/.pyenv/bin:/home/pi/.cargo/bin /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1670923014.7820504-10195-255321159434435/AnsiballZ_command.py && sleep 0
```

Any idea how I can debug this further?

Thanks!

Comment: The most common reason for a shell/command task hanging for ever is that it waits for user input. If this is the case see `expect` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I was able to fix it. The "hanging" was not realy related to ansible itself but to poetry. I needed to set an additional environment variable `PYTHON_KEYRING_BACKEND: keyring.backends.null.Keyring`. The reason why it was working fine when I executed the poetry config manually on the remote host was that I already set the environment variable in the .bashrc on the remote host.

More reference:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/634262/pip-hangs-on-loading-macos-when-installing-a-package

Comment: Sounds like it might be this bug: [Keyring errors during non-publishing operations #1917](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/1917)